# How to undo delete operation in android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, soft-delete

I performed the database operations in Android. But I need to undo the deleted row in Android SQLite database. Can anyone help me?

Comment: database operation  hard delete or soft delete  ?

Answer (score 2):

you can add a new field called is_deleted, you set the flag as true or false. please remember update your select query including the flag in WHERE clause. If you want to undo it, just flip the flag. it is called soft-deletion. the drawback is you need to design a garbage collection solution. like if the user leaves the screen, delete it permanently.  or use time based solution. delete those like 1 week old.

Comment: This is the best approach.

Comment: I wrote the following code
                                   
public void deleteNotes() {
        final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(mRelativeLayout, "Item is deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        is_deleted = 1;
        snackbar.setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                is_deleted =0;
            }
        });
        snackbar.show();

        DBOperations.deleteStudent(mDBHelper, id, is_deleted);
But is_deleted value is taking as 1 itself even i am pressing undo

Answer (score 1):

You can implement **Soft Delete**, in soft delete instead of delete **physically** you have a **Deleted** field and if you delete that field value of deleted column will be "1" then you can undo deletion.

Some thing like this:

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
| id         | column 01    | ...          | column N     | deleted   |
+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
```